# How to verify if checkbox is checked or unchecked in java for android studio?

Tags: java, android-studio

I have in my quiz a question (q7) with 4 possible answers checkbox ( answer71, answer72, answer73 and answer74). The right answers ar  answer72 and answer73. How can I verify (in java on android studio) if only the 2 good answers ar  checked (and the 2 wrong answers ar not checked) and then to make the score =+1. Thank you.

Comment: a) your formatting is horrible, b) learn what `if` means or actually think for 2 seconds when you're supposed to do your homework instead of copypasting your assignment, c) it's `+=`, not `=+`. thanks you.

Answer (score 2):

You can call the method `.isChecked()` on the checkbox.
And write a logic where you check whether the required checkboxes are selected.

`if(checkbox1.isChecked()) {`do something...`}`

As you want multiple checked boxes, you can run a loop.

```
List<CheckBox> items = new ArrayList<CheckBox>();
for (CheckBox item : items) {
    if(item.isChecked()) { 
        String text=item.getText().toString();
    }
}
```